# How to format a timestamp to string with fractional seconds in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datetime-format

This is a pretty straightforward question that I cannot seem to find the answer to.

I am working in BigQuery and have a timestamp:

```
2022-01-02 13:00:01.5849
```

I want to convert this to a string with all dashes, colons and spaces removed. End result should look like this:

```
202201021300015849
```

I am able to get everything before the decimal formatted fine but can't seem to figure out how to grab the fractional seconds.

This is what I have working so far:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', timestamp '2022-01-02 13:00:01.5849')
```

The output of this is:

```
20220102130001
```

Obviously this is missing the .5849 fractional seconds

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d%H%M%E*S', timestamp '2022-01-02 13:00:01.5849'), '.', '')
```